# SQLAlchemy behaves differently on Windows and Linux when connecting to Oracle

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a simple python script that connects to an Oracle database. The connection is setup as follows (summarized):

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://username:password@localhost:1521/?service_name=mydb", arraysize=1000)   
conn = engine.connect()
df = pd.read_sql("select count(*) from dual",conn)
```

The above works fine if i run it on my Windows 11 laptop. However if i move the script to a Linux server, i get the following error:

```
ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object: 'select count(*) from dual'
```

After a bit of googling, i found out that sqlalchemy does not accept strings i had to change the read_sql call to the following for it to work in linux:

```
df = pd.read_sql(text("select count(*) from dual") ,conn)
```

What i don't understand is why is it that if i run the script in Windows i don't have to make that change to convert the query to text whereas i have to do it on Linux. I suspect that maybe the Oracle drivers are behaving differently on each OS?

Comment: Are you running the same version of SQLAlchemy on both machines?

Comment: This won't be the Oracle driver.  It sounds very much like a SQLAlchemy 2 change.